# How to check if ID exists in database, otherwise insert it into database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, exists

I have a code which generates a 6 digit random number with the code `mt_rand(100000,999999);` and stores it in the variable `$student_id`. I check if the number exists in the database with the following code.

```
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connect, "SELECT id FROM students WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1")) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $student_id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $db_id);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
}

if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1) {
    echo "The ID exists.";
} else {
    // Insert $student_id into database
}
```

This code can insert the ID into the database if `mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 0`. But, if the ID already exists, it won't generate a new 6 digit random ID, it won't check if that ID already exists in the database, etc. I can imagine that I would have to use some kind of loop which will keep generating a random ID untill it doesn't exists in the database and then insert it into the database. I've read about a few loops (like `while` or `for`), but I don't have any idea how to use them.

Can anyone help me out with this or help me in the right direction?

Cheers

Comment: Why don't you just use an auto-increment id field? Why does the student id have to be "random"? Also, which database are you using?

Comment: Because I want the ID to have 6 digits and I thought auto-increment starts with 1. Basically there's no other reason than that I just want the ID to be random (although that's a bit silly). I use MySQL as my database.

Comment: No problem. See my new answer :)

Comment: Almost always better to attempt the insert and handle the error (it *is* marked as unique in the DB isn't it?). Otherwise, between checking and insertion, it might have been inserted by another instance of the code (unless you're building a system that's only used by a single user, which is a rarity these days)

Comment: Yes, it is marked as unique. Hmm, I haven't thought about it that way. Because other people will be able to use the system. Although I hope the chance is not very big that when I'm creating a student with a random ID, someone else is also creating a student with the same random ID.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you just need 6 digits, use an auto increment column, but have it start at `100000` instead of the usual starting value of `1`.

You can do it at the time you create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -- other columns
)
AUTO_INCREMENT = 100000;
```

See this demonstrated on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98f1e/1).

Or if the table already exists with an auto increment column, you can set it:

```
ALTER TABLE MYTABLE AUTO_INCREMENT = 100000;
```

Comment: That's a great solution. It makes way more sense than generating a random number, checking if it already exists, etc. I'll mark this as my solution as I will use this in my code. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use autoincrement field, you can change your query in this way:

```
SELECT id FROM students WHERE id = ? limit 1
```

becames

```
SELECT count(id) FROM students WHERE id = ?
```

So you can check if the result is > 0 (exists) or not (not exists)

Comment: Thanks! That's true, I was missing that part in my query. Although I still need the query to be looped until the result is 0, and then perform an INSERT query.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple PHP solution for this, while Bohemian answer is valid for a MySQL approach, here is a way to do it using do...while loop as the questionnaire wanted.

```
<?php

 do {
$unique_id = mt_rand(100000, 900000);//generates 6 random numbers
$query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "select * from users where unique_id='$unique_id'");
} while(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0);// repeats loop till generated id is not found

 //php insert query comes here
 
   ?>
```